# Convert nested mongoDB document into flat pandas DataFrame (Array of objects within array of objects)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I am trying to convert mongoDB documents into a flat pandas dataframe structure.

An example of my mongoDB collection structure:

```
data = collection.find_one({'ID':300})
print(data)

{'_id': "ObjectId('5cd932299f6b7d4c9b95af6c')",
 'ID': 300,
 'updated': 23424,
 'data': [
     { 'meta': 8,
       'data': [
           {'value1': 1, 'value2': 2}, 
           {'value1': 3, 'value2': 4}
       ]
     },
     { 'meta': 9,
       'data': [
           {'value1': 5, 'value2': 6}
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

When i put this into a pandas dataframe, I get

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

| _id                      | ID  | updated | data                                              
|
|--------------------------|-----|---------|------------------------ ---------------------------|
| 5cd936779f6b7d4c9b95af6d | 300 | 23424   | {'meta': 8, 'data': [{'value1': 1, 'value2': 2... |
| 5cd936779f6b7d4c9b95af6d | 300 | 23424   | {'meta': 9, 'data': [{'value1': 5, 'value2': 6}]} |
```

When I iterate through the dataframe with pd.concat I get

```
df.rename(columns={'data':'data1'}, inplace=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(list(df['data1']))], axis=1).drop('data1', 1)
df3 = pd.concat([df2, pd.DataFrame(list(df2['data']))], axis=1).drop('data', 1)
print(df3)

| _id                      | ID  | updated | meta | 0                          | 1                          |
|--------------------------|-----|---------|------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| 5cd936779f6b7d4c9b95af6d | 300 | 23424   | 8    | {'value1': 1, 'value2': 2} | {'value1': 3, 'value2': 4} |
| 5cd936779f6b7d4c9b95af6d | 300 | 23424   | 9    | {'value1': 5, 'value2': 6} | None                       |
```

The lowest level objects of the lowest level array has always the same names.

Therefore I want:

```
| ID  | updated | meta | value1 | value2 |
|-----|---------|------|--------|--------|
| 300 | 23424   | 8    | 1      | 2      |
| 300 | 23424   | 8    | 3      | 4      |
| 300 | 23424   | 9    | 5      | 6      |
```

Am I on the wrong track?

What would be the most convenient way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized that mongoDB can do all the heavy lifting.

Working code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongoClient = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = mongoClient.DB_NAME
collection = db.COLLECTION_NAME

pipeline = [
    {'$match':{'ID':300}},
    {"$unwind":{'path': '$data', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}},
    {"$unwind":{'path': '$data.data', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}},
    {'$project':{
      'ID':'$ID',
      'updated':"$updated",
      'meta':"$data.meta",
      'value1':"$data.data.value1",
      'value2':"$data.data.value2"
    }}
]

#Make empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame() 

#add each doc as a new row in dataframe
for doc in collection.aggregate(pipeline): 
    df = df.append(doc,ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
| ID  | updated | meta | value1 | value2 |
|-----|---------|------|--------|--------|
| 300 | 23424   | 8    | 1      | 2      |
| 300 | 23424   | 8    | 3      | 4      |
| 300 | 23424   | 9    | 5      | 6      |
```

Comment: Thanks @sinB  .... also the df could be directly created as 
              df = pd.DataFrame(collection.aggregate(pipeline))

Answer (score 6):

@sinB - You can further improve this by removing the for loop (It will cause issue when dealing with database with many documents). You don't need loop anyway as the result can be converted into pandas dataframe with single command.

Instead of this:

```
#add each doc as a new row in dataframe
for doc in collection.aggregate(pipeline): 
    df = df.append(doc,ignore_index=True)
```

You can use this

```
query_result = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
query_result = list(query_result)
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(query_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to solve it in the most hideous way.

```
def flatten(data):
    a = {}
    def make_dict(data):
        for i in list(data):
            if isinstance(data[i], list):
                for j in data[i]:
                    make_dict(j)
            else:
                a.update({i:[]})
        return data

    def add_to_dict(data):
        for i in list(data):
            if isinstance(data[i], list):
                for j in data[i]:
                    add_to_dict(j)
            else:
                a[i].append(data[i])
        max = 0
        for i in a:
            if len(a[i]) > max:
                max = len(a[i])
        for i in a:
            if len(a[i]) < max:
                a[i].append(a[i][-1])

    make_dict(data)
    add_to_dict(data)
    return a


pd.DataFrame(flatten(data))
```

Output:

```
| ID  | updated | meta | value1 | value2 |
|-----|---------|------|--------|--------|
| 300 | 23424   | 8    | 1      | 2      |
| 300 | 23424   | 8    | 3      | 4      |
| 300 | 23424   | 9    | 5      | 6      |
```

I can't imagine this is a good solution, so please feel free to help me with a better one.